# Startup several applications on boot (each in their own terminal) + Auto-Mount Harddisk

Tags: command-line, 16.04, scripts, lubuntu, startup

When I boot up my linux server, I always have to run the following things manually:

1. Start up our MC server by a single command line
2. Start up my telegram bot by a single command line
3. Start up my DNS update client by a single command line
4. (login to a harddrive)

What would be a good approach to automate this process? I've seen some "minecraft startup scrips", but they contain a lot of lines of code which is absolutely unnecessary in my case. I use my own slim server-manager that can be run by a simple command.

The goal is, that I boot up my server and everything gets done automatically, after I logged in with my user (I'm the only user on this system).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply go to `Start up Applications`, and add a new entry, name it as you wish and write the following in the command box:

`gnome-terminal -e "command"`

*Instead of `gnome-terminal` you can use whichever terminal you like. Substitute *command* by any of your commands, easier to do it just one command per entry.

Comment: Sweet! Now I need something to get the HD into autoboot, but that's another matter. **For everyone using Lubuntu:** You can find the option in: `Preferences -> Default applications for LXSession`. Just type in your command and click "add". If you use `LXTerminal` like me, type `lxterminal -e ` before each command.

Comment: By *autoboot* you mean to mount at boot? @TrudleR Sorry I didnt realize you put the tag for Lubuntu, thanks for adding that in your comment.

Comment: Yeah, auto mount, not boot, sry. I always have to click it and type the PW before accessing it. :)

Comment: @TrudleR I found this, hope it can help you. https://myubuntublog.wordpress.com/2009/05/25/auto-mount-usb-hard-drive-at-boot/

Comment: That didn't work sadly. :(

Comment: Hi :) Do you have any idea how to address sudo commands using this option? My MC-Server gets some Exceptions for some things it does if it's not running with sudo priviledges (when writig to disk or executing programs). I already set `chmod 777 -R` to check, but that didn't solve the problem, so I ask in general on how to run sudo-level-commands.

Comment: @TrudleR I think it would be better if you would post a new question regarding that. But here is a possible solution: **USE WITH CAUTION** - **open sudoers**  `sudo gedit /etc/sudoers`, **edit it** adding the following line `your_login ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: command`. Now that *command* should be able to run without `sudo password`. Its **relatively save** to do this, as you are only allowing that particular command, but still make sure theres no way that could imply any **security risk**.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I messed up and now I can't use sudo-priviledges anymore. I will have too boot a live cd to change this file back to its original state, which I won't do right now, since I need to connect an external monitor for this. For everyone trying to do this: NEVER edit this file manually! Use `visudo` for this matter!

Comment: @TrudleR Im sorry to hear that :/ Do you know what did you exactly do wrong? Or did you make a backup copy of the  file first so you could use it in case smth wrong happened?

Comment: Even if I did, you need sudo permission to edit/move/create files in there. :) As soon as you do something wrong, your sudo rights are gone forever and you can't replace it with a backup file.

Comment: @TrudleR True that, that was stupid of me to think about. Im sorry that happened to you, I should have strongly suggeted using `visudo`. In case you need any help to fix it, please ask again on the site.

Comment: I started a new question here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/855081/steps-to-automatically-let-my-user-run-a-complex-command-at-login

Answer (score 1):

Since 1-3 have been answered, for point 4 in Lubuntu you should have an application Disks - try checking out the Mount Options (in More actions... menu).

my 2 cents

Comment: This is a bit unspecific. Even using google, I wasn't able to find what you suggest here.

Comment: I saw you already managed to find a solution, anyway I meant from the graphical menu', I attached an image to make it clearer (and in my knowledge this is specific to Lubuntu distro and not at all generic)

Comment: well the image :) I should be able to see mount options at startup https://postimg.org/image/a6w5ybjg3/

Comment: Thx. Sadly, this option doesn't exist on lubuntu. :( I wonder why.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for **point 4**. After a lot of research, this is the easiest way I found to achieve this:

1. Create a directory, where you want to mount the drive (mount point):

`sudo mkdir /media/username/mysuperharddisk`

(replace `username` with your login-name and `mysuperharddisk` with a random name you want to give your harddrive.)

2. Open up /etc/rc.local

On a default Lubuntu, you do that by typing:

`sudo leafpad /etc/rc.local`

3. BEFORE the line `exit 0`, insert the command:

`mount /dev/sdb1 /media/username/mysuperharddisk`

ATTENTION: You need to replace `sdb1` with whatever hard disk you want to auto-mount. (If you manually mount the HDD, you can check what name it has.) It should sound similar like my sdb1 here. The number can be different or the last letter (a instead of b).

(replace `username` with your login-name and `mysuperharddisk` with what you specified at point 1.)

Done. A very nice way to achieve this. :)

Comment: Glad to see you managed after all :D