# Steps to automatically let my user run a complex command at login

Tags: command-line, 16.04, bash, lubuntu, autostart

[I already messed my system up once](https://askubuntu.com/a/840393/272169), so I'm gonna ask more specifically:

**What are the steps to do, so that command can run with sudo privileges at startup?**

Here is what I know so far:
I have this command, containing "":

```
java -jar /home/joe/minecraft/minecraft_server/MCpal.jar /media/joe/Chest/mc_backups 12288 server.jar "overviewer.py --rendermodes=smooth-lighting {2}/Galamor /home/joe/minecraft/Overviewer/map"
```

I went to `Preferences -> Default applications for LXSession` and added the line: `lxterminal -e COMMAND` to the autostart section.

This starts a terminal running my command (in this case, starting my minecraft server manager). Something within this process needs sudo permissions. Since I wrote this program myself and since I trust Mojang, I just want to run this command at sudo level without needing to type in my password.

I tried to use `sudo visudo` to give my user the rights to run it without typing a password. I don't seem to get the synthax right.

Here is, how I think it should be:

```
joe ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: java -jar /home/joe/minecraft/minecraft_server/MCpal.jar /media/joe/Chest/mc_backups 12288 server.jar "overviewer.py --rendermodes=smooth-lighting {2}/Galamor /home/joe/minecraft/Overviewer/map"
```

Where is the error here?

I would love it if you could answer step by step. Maybe I used the wrong line to type it or whatever it could be.

Comment: I doubt Minecraft needs root rights and really think that is a bad idea. Who is the owner and what are the permissions on the `/media/joe/Chest/mc_backups` path?

Comment: @Byte Commander: It's not just MC, also my setup of overviewer and my server manager.

Comment: Assuming this is a server, you may trust that Mojang isn't trying to harm you, but you shouldn't trust that they write bug-free code that someone connecting to your server can't use to break into the account the server is running under. That's why servers that are installed through `apt install` tend to create a new account to run the server under, so that any damage is limited to that account.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, you would use a service to run as a specific user at a certain time during boot.

I think the ideal solution to "How to run a Minecraft server at login" is to create a new user, `minecraft`, and make sure that your HTTP server (`apache` or `nginx`) has access to those files generated by `overviewer`.  When you run `overviewer`, you want to do it as the `minecraft` user.

The following assumes that `/home/minecraft/minecraft-1.7/` is the directory that contains your minecraft server files, such as the `world` directory, and that within that directory, you have minecraft_server.jar.  Also, `nginx` is used to act as an HTTP server.

You can create the this user with `sudo useradd minecraft -m`.  By not setting a password, you'll only be able to become this user with `sudo su - minecraft`.

The `minecraft` user would have the following cron entry (`crontab -e` as `minecraft`):

```
0 * * * * /usr/bin/overviewer.py --rendermodes=smooth-lighting,cave /home/minecraft/minecraft-1.7/world/ /home/minecraft/minecraft-1.7/www-overviewer/
```

Ideally, you'll have the Minecraft server run using upstart (`/etc/systemd/system/minecraft-server.service`):

```
[Unit] 
Description=Minecraft Server

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/minecraft/minecraft-1.7/
User=minecraft
Group=minecraft
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=20 5
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -Xms1536M -Xmx1536M -jar minecraft_server.jar nogui

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Enable it to start at boot with `sudo systemctl enable minecraft-server`, and tell it to start now with `sudo systemctl start minecraft-server`.

...while you configure NGINX with:

```
server {
    listen 8888;
    client_max_body_size 50M;

    server_name _ minecraft.DOMAIN.tld

    charset UTF-8;

    expires max;
    gzip                on;
    gzip_buffers        16 8k;
    gzip_comp_level     4;
    gzip_http_version   1.0;
    gzip_min_length     1280;
    gzip_types          text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript text/x-js;
    gzip_vary           on;
    gzip_static         on;

    add_header Cache-Control  "public";

    location / {
        root  /home/minecraft/minecraft-1.7/www-overviewer;
    }

}
```

There is **no** reason to run `minecraft`, `overviewer`, etc as root, and should be avoided.